# How to search for posts that contain "Falcon" but are not about a SpaceX rocket?

Tags: support, search

The Live Science article [Why a microwave-beam experiment will launch aboard the Air Force’s secretive X-37B space plane](https://www.livescience.com/microwave-beam-military-space-plane.html) says:

> This time around though, a bit more information is on offer. According to a Space Force statement, the X-37B will carry a "service module" into space with the spaceplane's first payload of scientific experiments. It will deploy a satellite known as **FalconSat-8** with some experiments aboard, while PRAM-FX and another experiment will remain attached to the X-37B.

A quick search for the exact match "FalconSat" or "FalconSat-8" doesn't turn up anything but when I loosen the criteria I get hundreds of posts in search result.

Is there some way to search this site for posts that contain the string "Falcon" (upper or lower case) either embedded in a longer term or separated by spaces or a hyphen, but do not contain "Falcon-9" or "Falcon-Heavy"?

I seem to remember a question about an educational military satellite that was called a Falcon of some sort but I'm not sure if I'm mis-remembering something else.

Answer (score 6):

You can exclude certain terms with the `-` operator, as described in the [Help Center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/searching). In this case, since the keywords you want to exclude, you have to make them exact matches with `"`. Searching for

```
"falcon" -falcon-9 -"falcon-heavy"
```

gives [133 results](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22falcon%22+-%22falcon-9%22+-%22falcon-heavy%22); it looks like it returns both posts using the word 'Falcon' on its own, and also 'falcon-1'. (I say looks like since that's highlighted; it could be that the highlighting function works differently than the search itself.)

If this doesn't work, I'm afraid you'll have to resort to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/); luckily, Space.SE is small enough to do a full text search on post bodies. But crafting a decent `LIKE` clause might be tricky.

Comment: Okay I'll give this a whirl, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove tags using -[spacex], for instance. Try [this query](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22falcon%22%20-%22falcon-9%22%20-%22falcon-heavy%22%20-%22spacex%22%20-%22falcon%209r%22%20-tesla%20-dragon%20-%5Bspacex%5D%20-%5Bfalcon-9%5D).

Answer (score 3):

You can abandon the largely useless stack exchange search capability and use duckduckgo, which supports the negation operator much better than google.

`falcon -spacex -heavy -9 -9s site:space.stackexchange.com` works pretty well.

[image]